# How can I use image_path inside Rails 3 Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

An identical question has been asked before 
[AssetTagHelper::image_path outside views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804082/assettaghelperimage-path-outside-views) 
but the solution does not work for Rails 3.

I have a requirement where I am returning some data using JSON format and part of the data needs to return the full path of the image. I am building the response in the controller and calling render :json. I am also specifying an asset_host in the environment.rb so I need a way to include that in the returned data from inside a Rails controller.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use **view_context** in your controller when doing 'view' tasks like generating links. The good thing about it is you don't have to **include** the view helpers in your controller.

e.g. in your controller you can create a variable which will be a html link with **link_to** or **url_for** if you just want the link, '**only_path**' option set to false should give you absolute url.

```
link = view_context.url_for(:action => 'login', :controller => 'members', :only_path => false)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: For me, I needed to generate a CSS image url to an asset which has a digest in the filename.  Thanks to you, Barlow, I came up with this:  `"url(#{view_context.asset_path('dir/filename.png')})"`