# Rails - How would I get the URL of a single image asset in the controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, url, controller, actionview, actionviewhelper

I've tried including `ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper` and then using the `image_path()` method however it gives me grief:

```
undefined local variable or method `config' for ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper:Module
```

There's probably something simple I'm missing. Any ideas?

Comment: Please explain where are you including the module.

Comment: Oh sorry- I'm trying to do this in a controller.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the solution in Barlow's answer here: [How can I use image_path inside Rails 3 Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943188/how-can-i-use-image-path-inside-rails-3-controller)

```
view_context.image_path('/path/to/image')
```

seems to work for me, no need to include helpers in the Controller